# Automatically Extracting feed links (atom, rss,etc) from webpages

Tags: python, api, rss, feed, atom-feed

I have a huge list of URLs and my task is to feed them to a python script which should spit out the feed urls if there are any. Is there an API library or code out there that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second waffle paradox in recommending [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download) for parsing the HTML and then getting the <link rel="alternate"> tags, where the feeds are referenced. The code I usually use:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as parser

def detect_feeds_in_HTML(input_stream):
    """ examines an open text stream with HTML for referenced feeds.

    This is achieved by detecting all ``link`` tags that reference a feed in HTML.

    :param input_stream: an arbitrary opened input stream that has a :func:`read` method.
    :type input_stream: an input stream (e.g. open file or URL)
    :return: a list of tuples ``(url, feed_type)``
    :rtype: ``list(tuple(str, str))``
    """
    # check if really an input stream
    if not hasattr(input_stream, "read"):
        raise TypeError("An opened input *stream* should be given, was %s instead!" % type(input_stream))
    result = []
    # get the textual data (the HTML) from the input stream
    html = parser(input_stream.read())
    # find all links that have an "alternate" attribute
    feed_urls = html.findAll("link", rel="alternate")
    # extract URL and type
    for feed_link in feed_urls:
        url = feed_link.get("href", None)
        # if a valid URL is there
        if url:
            result.append(url)
    return result
```

Answer (score 7):

There's [`feedfinder`](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/feedfinder/):

```
>>> import feedfinder
>>>
>>> feedfinder.feed('scripting.com')
'http://scripting.com/rss.xml'
>>>
>>> feedfinder.feeds('scripting.com')
['http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/atom.xml', 
 'http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/index.rdf', 
 'http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/rss.xml']
>>>
```

Comment: feedfinder is no longer maintained, but now there is [`feedfinder2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedfinder2).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any existing library, but Atom or RSS feeds are usually indicated with a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section as such:

```
<link rel="alternative" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://link.to/feed">
<link rel="alternative" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://link.to/feed">
```

Straightforward way would be downloading and parsing these URL's with an HTML parser like [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) and getting the `href` attribute of relevant `<link>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how well-formed the information in these feeds are (e.g., Are all the links in the form of `http://.../`?  Do you know if they will all be in `href` or `link` tags?  Are all the links in the feeds going to be to other feeds?  etc.), I'd recommend anything from a simple regex to a straight-up parsing module to extract links from the feeds.

As far as parsing modules go, I can only recommend [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download).  Though even the best parser will only go so far--esp in the case I mentioned above, if you can't guarantee all links in the data are going to be links to other feeds; then you have to do some additional crawling and probing on your own.