# Extract RSS Feed url from

Tags: rss, web-crawler, feed, atom-feed, scraper

I have 100 websites that have RSS feeds exposed in different locations. These locations have several RSS feed links pointing at different feeds. Its nearly identical to the BBC Rss feeds page 
http://www.bbc.com/news/10628494

Site 1 : domain1.com/rss
Site 2 : domain2.com/enviroments/rss

Is there any way to extract out the rss links to the each feed xml.

Somthing similar to this 
[Automatically Extracting feed links (atom, rss,etc) from webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7883581) but I would like to only give the site. So that I get all possible rss feeds for a particular site.

I want to have a list of all the rss feeds from the 100 websites. So then I can monitor them on a dashboard. Oh the feeds aee mixed bith atom and rss.

What I have done. I have looked into apache nutch and the parse-feed plugin. Scrapy was the next option but I am still not sure this what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, a website that offers RSS feed(s) indicates so in the header of at least the home page, some every single page.

There is an example of an RSS feed:

```
<link href="http://snapwebsites.org/rss.xml"
      title="Snap! A C++ Open Source CMS RSS"
      type="application/rss+xml"
      rel="alternate">
```

Note that the type will vary slightly between websites. For example some websites may use `text` instead of `application` (which is wrong, but XML is text...) There is also `application/atom+xml`. You may also have both formats.

If that's not available, then you'd have to check the home page or other pages for anchor links to an RSS feed, which means:

- Parse the HTML
- Look for anchors
- Read the `href` attribute
- Check the destination to see whether it returns an XML file
- If you get an xml file (starts with `<?xml ...`) then check the root tag:

1. 'rss' -- RSS format (version is an attribute)
2. 'feed' -- Atom format

I have an example on the following page that includes the `<link ...>` tag in the header:

http://snapwebsites.org/implementation/feature-requirements/feed-feature-core-atom-rss-20-etc

I have to say, without that link, it will be quite a bit harder to find the RSS feeds. That being said, on many websites the feeds files make use of an extension (.rss, .atom, .xml) and that could be used to simplified the search. Yet, more and more, feeds look like directory names (`.../blah` or `.../foo` cannot be distinguished from a standard HTML page or a feed, so the only way is to read the file at the destination and check the file format; the `Content-Type` of the HTTP reply should be `application/rss+xml` or `application/atom+xml` too... like the header link `type=...` attribute)

---

As a side note, although very unlikely (I've not really seen it on a live website), it is possible to use the [`Link: ...` HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) to indicate... links just the same as the `<link ...>` tag found in the HTML header. If you have access to the HTTP header ([here is how to do it in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)), then it's worth looking for those headers to see whether one of them is an RSS feed.

Comment: I hope the guys have managed to put the feed links in with the proper type.  So that they are easy to pick up. As I would imagine the crawling will take far longer if it there isnt.

Comment: Yes. Well... once get the link you're good. On the flip side, if you have many feeds on a single website, it is not unlikely that they won't all appear in the header `link` tags. It depends whether you want to get all the feeds or not.

Comment: Your right of course all the links wont show up in the header. We will have to simply crawl all pages and parse the content to  check if it has a Content-Type we are looking for.